# test tinymce in vue-test-utils but got "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined" error

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, vue-test-utils

I'm new in `vue-test-utils` and want to write `test.spec.js` for my `Tinymce/index` component, but when i run `npm test` i got this error:

● Tinymce › encountered a declaration exception

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

  122 |     initTinymce() {
  123 |       const _this = this
> 124 |       window.tinymce.init({
      | ^
  125 |         selector: `#${this.tinymceId}`,
  126 |         height: 430,
  127 |         min_height: 430,
```

And here is my `test.spec.js`

```
import Tinymce from '@/components/Tinymce/index'
import { mount, createLocalVue, shallowMount  } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Element from 'element-ui'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Element)

describe('Tinymce', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Tinymce, {
    localVue,
    attachToDocument: true
  })

  it('emit functions run correct by order', () => {
    expect(wrapper.emittedByOrder().map(e => e.name)).toEqual(['input', 'backImgAdd'])
  })
})
```

Did i miss some `config`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `Tinymce` component working correctly outside of the test?
How do you attach the `tinymce` object to the `window` object?
So maybe you can debug when the `window.tinymce` gets defined and the `init()` method is available.
If you could give us more info how `Tinymce` component looks like,
it would be helpfull to check if there is something wrong with the lifecycle etc.